# How can I root my Motorola Fire XT316?

Tags: rooting

I'm new Android user and want to root my Motorola XT316 with Android 2.3.4.

I found [this guide](https://sites.google.com/site/wikihowtosetup/root-motorola-xt316-or-xt510) but is based on Windows XP, and I use Linux (Fedora 16). Is there another method?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but here are the steps to root this device. I am posting it so the [*Rooting Index*](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) is up to date and has an answer for this device. YMMV

These steps should work for XT311/XT316/XT317, XT530/XT531, XT532, and XT611

Steps are from [this thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1678811):

*Looks like this does require Windows*

#### Required Tools / Files

1. SuperOneClick 2.3.3.0
2. SUT LR 1.8.2 (Doesn't seem to be working on 64-bit systems)
3. FXX_PR3_NV.xml and NvDefinition.xml [Available On The XDA Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1678811)

#### Before Rooting

Prepare your phone by doing the following:

- Go to Settings > Applications > CHECK "Unknown Sources"
- Go to Settings > Applications > Developer > CHECK "USB Debugging" and "Stay Awake"
- Connect your phone via USB, when prompted DO NOT select USB Mass Storage.
- Extract FXX_PR3_NV.xml and NvDefinition.xml from the attached zip file in to a folder

#### Rooting

- Now, install SUT LR
- Run the app
- Select the FXX_PR3_NV.xml [ensure NvDefinition.xml is also in the same folder as FXX_PR3_NV.xml]
- Your phone will restart.

---

Here is another solution that looks like it may not require a Windows PC

1. Extract the file [Available On The XDA Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1678811)
2. Mount /system as RW.
3. Open Root Browser and copy bootmenu folder from sdcard/XT530 and paste it in /system.
4. Open Pimp My Rom and Add universal init.d support.
5. Create 97bootmenu manually. (For this using ES file explorer is recommended)
   Steps:

   - Open /system/etc/init.d
   - Create a file, name it 97bootmenu.
   - Open the file as text Type:

     #!/system/bin/sh
     stop
     exec /system/bootmenu/binary/bootmenu
   - save the file
6. Change permissions of 97bootmenu to `rwx r-- r--`
7. Reboot your phone.
8. Now your phone will start at bootmenu.
9. Select Recovery>Custom Recovery

---

To boot the device normally again, open a console/terminal window, while the device is connected via usb.

```
cd path-to-adb
adb shell
rm -R /system/etc/init.d/97bootmenu
exit
adb reboot
```